# Replace Rare Word Tokens : Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to replace all rare words with an identifier 'UNK' in a corpus. The below code works but is pretty slow. Is there a better smarter way? EDIT: The bottle neck is the `rareWordstoUNK` function - the prior parts are very fast. There are about 80,000 rows in my pandas series.

`X_train` is a pandas series, where each 'row' is a list of word tokens such as `['this','is','my','first', 'sentence']`. I loop through and create a dictionary of word frequencies and then create a list of the non-rare words (`frequency >1` in this example). Then I want to apply this to future data where if the word is rare or maybe had not been seen before, the token is replaced with 'UNK'

```
    wordFreqDict={}

#dictionary of word counts    
    for tokenlist in X_train:
        for token in tokenlist:
            if token in wordFreqDict:
                wordFreqDict[token]=wordFreqDict[token]+1
            else:
                wordFreqDict[token]=1

    #non rare tokens        
    FreqWordsGT1=[k for k,v in wordFreqDict.iteritems() if v >1]

    #pass in list and replace those not in keeplist with 'UNK'
    def rareWordstoUNK(tokenlist,keeplist, replaceToken='UNK'):
        return [w if w in keeplist else replaceToken for w in tokenlist  ]

#apply pandas series 


       X_train=X_train.apply(rareWordstoUNK, args=(FreqWordsGT1,'UNK'))
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36310156/5741205) - it's pretty similar to your task

Comment: You might also benefit from using `frozenset` for the `keeplist`.

Comment: @MaxU That example counts words, but that is not the issue - the pain point is the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I think a slight change in approach will lead to a big increase in performance. Your `keeplist` is very likely to have a large number of items in it, as a result `w in keeplist` comparison is likely to be slow. According to [python time complexity data](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) this is an O(n) operation. So you effectively have a nested loop inside rareWordstoUNK.

Why not build an infrequent words list and compare against that instead? That list is likely to be smaller so O(m) < O(n)

Also as suggested by @ChrisP you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a list. `x in s` operation is O(1) according to the link above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that I need to essentially say 'any words that are not in the large list need to be recoded'. This includes words that were not seen in the training data but may be in future data.

Answer (score 0):

As @e4c5 has already mentioned:

> `w in keeplist` comparison is likely to be slow

Get Item from dict will cost you: O(1)

so i would rewrite your function in the following way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# change your `wordFreqDict` to defaultdict
wordFreqDict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

your code for filling up the `wordFreqDict`

```
def rareWordstoUNK(tokenlist, wordfreq, replaceToken='UNK'):
    """
    will replace all words with frequency <= 1,
    including those which haven't been seen yet (i.e. if this word is not in `wordfreq`)
    """
    return [w if w in wordfreq[w] > 1 else replaceToken for w in tokenlist]

X_train=X_train.apply(rareWordstoUNK, args=(wordFreqDict,'UNK'))
```

and then call it like this:

```
X_train=X_train.apply(rareWordstoUNK, args=(wordFreqDict,'UNK'))
```