# Frequency of each word in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which look like following

```
    key message                                         Final Category
0   1   I have not received my gifts which I ordered ok      voucher
1   2   hth her wells idyll McGill kooky bbc.co              noclass
2   3   test test test 1 test                                noclass
3   4   test                                                 noclass
4   5   hello where is my reward points                      other
5   6   hi, can you get koovs coupons or vouchers here       options
6   7   Hi Hey when you people will include amazon an        options
```

I want to get a {key:{key:value},..} type of data structure where first groupby Final Category and for each category i have a dictionary for each words frequecy.
For example 
i can group all noclass which will look like following {'noclass':{'test':5, '1':1, 'hth':1,'her':1 ....}, }

I am new to SOF so sorry for not writing well.
Thanks

Comment: you can do it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36310156/5741205) You will have to export resulting DF to dictionary at the end...

Comment: you can use [CountVecorizer](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+CountVectorizer&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr) from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`

Comment: @MaxU thanks a lot for suggestion after few minute research i have been able to cleanup my data-set to make it feedable  to classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more eloquent way to do this, but here it is with a bunch of nested for loops:

```
final_cat_list = df['Final Category'].unique()

word_count = {}
for f in final_cat_list:
    word_count[f] = {}
    message_list = list(df.loc[df['Final Category'] == f, 'key message'])
    for m in message_list:
        word_list = m.split(" ")
        for w in word_list:
            if w in word_count[f]:
                word_count[f][w] += 1
            else:
                word_count[f][w] = 1
```

Comment: @S044 Thanks u so much.

Answer (score 0):

This modifies the original df, so you might wanna copy it first

```
from collections import Counter
df["message"] = df["message"].apply(lambda message: message + " ")
df.groupby(["Final Category"]).sum().applymap(lambda message: Counter(message.split()))
```

What this code does: first it adds a space to the end of all messages. This will come in later.
Then it groups by Final Category, and sums up the messages in each group. This is where the trailing space is important, otherwise the last word of a message would get glued to the first word of the next. (Summing is concatenation for strings)

Then you split the string along whitespace to get the words, and then you count.

Comment: seems good but code produces too much expection i need eye on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# copy/paste data (you can skip this since you already have a dataframe)
dict = {0 : {'key': 1 , 'message': "I have not received my gifts which I ordered ok",     'Final Category': 'voucher'},
        1 : {'key': 2 , 'message': "hth her wells idyll McGill kooky bbc.co",             'Final Category': 'noclass'},
        2 : {'key': 3 , 'message': "test test test 1 test",                               'Final Category': 'noclass'},
        3 : {'key': 4 , 'message': "test",                                                'Final Category': 'noclass'},
        4 : {'key': 5 , 'message': "hello where is my reward points",                   'Final Category': 'other'},
        5 : {'key': 6 , 'message': "hi, can you get koovs coupons or vouchers here",      'Final Category': 'options'},
        6 : {'key': 7 , 'message': "Hi Hey when you people will include amazon an",       'Final Category': 'options'}
        }

# make DataFrame (you already have one)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict).T

# break up text into words, combine by 'Final' in my case
df.message = df.message.str.split(' ')
final_df = df.groupby('Final Category').agg(np.sum)

# make final dictionary
final_dict = {}
for label,text in zip(final_df.index, final_df.message):  
    final_dict[label] = {w: text.count(w) for w in text}
```

Comment: we can't really define dictionary like that in this case as dataset is so huge 400k lines.

Comment: You already have a DataFrame, so you can ignore my initial `dict`. I just copy/pasted your data to have a workable example.